# Error with progress bar in kerasR. BrokenPipe error

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

when trying to learn the network using kerasR (R 3.6.2, Keras 2.3.1, Tensorflow 2.1.0) I'm getting the following error (only for number of epochs bigger than 1):

`Error in 'py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords)':  IOError: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
Detailed traceback:

File "/Users/tkubik/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1039, in fit    validation_steps=validation_steps)  File "/Users/tkubik/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training_arrays.py", line 217, in fit_loop    callbacks.on_epoch_end(epoch, epoch_logs)

File "/Users/tkubik/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 79, in on_epoch_end    callback.on_epoch_end(epoch, logs)

File "/Users/tkubik/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/callbacks.py", line 338, in on_epoch_end    self.progbar.update(self.seen, self.log_values)

File "/Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/library/keras/python/kerastools/progbar.py", line 23, in update_with_patch    update(self, current, values)

File "/Users/tkubik/.virtualenvs/r-tensorflow/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/utils/gen...`

The last trace points probably at generic_utils.py, but R cuts the trace here.
Does anybody know what should I do to either just get rid of this error or switch of the progress bar. I don't need it, but I'd like to observe the learning progression in any form.
Thank you very much!

Comment: To switch off the progress bar, set verbose to 0. `model.fit(X, Y, verbose=0)`

Comment: Thank you very much! This helped, but now I have no "live" output during learning process, since it is a silent mode. Both verbose=1 and verbose=2 result in Broken Pipe